# floating table header AND footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on the table and I want to modify the javascript code so that the 'footer' at the end of the table floats at the bottom similar to the way the header floats at the top.

```js
function UpdateTableHeaders() {
  $("div.divTableWithFloatingHeader").each(function() {
    var originalHeaderRow = $(".tableFloatingHeaderOriginal", this);
    var floatingHeaderRow = $(".tableFloatingHeader", this);
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + $(this).height())) {
      floatingHeaderRow.css("visibility", "visible");
      floatingHeaderRow.css("top", Math.min(scrollTop - offset.top, $(this).height() - floatingHeaderRow.height()) + "px");

      // Copy cell widths from original header
      $("th", floatingHeaderRow).each(function(index) {
        var cellWidth = $("th", originalHeaderRow).eq(index).css('width');
        $(this).css('width', cellWidth);
      });

      // Copy row width from whole table
      floatingHeaderRow.css("width", $(this).css("width"));
    } else {
      floatingHeaderRow.css("visibility", "hidden");
      floatingHeaderRow.css("top", "0px");
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table.tableWithFloatingHeader").each(function() {
    $(this).wrap("<div class=\"divTableWithFloatingHeader\" style=\"position:relative\"></div>");

    var originalHeaderRow = $("tr:first", this)
    originalHeaderRow.before(originalHeaderRow.clone());
    var clonedHeaderRow = $("tr:first", this)

    clonedHeaderRow.addClass("tableFloatingHeader");
    clonedHeaderRow.css("position", "absolute");
    clonedHeaderRow.css("top", "0px");
    //clonedHeaderRow.css("left", $(this).css("margin-left"));
    clonedHeaderRow.css("visibility", "hidden");

    originalHeaderRow.addClass("tableFloatingHeaderOriginal");
  });
  UpdateTableHeaders();
  $(window).scroll(UpdateTableHeaders);
  $(window).resize(UpdateTableHeaders);
});
```

```css
th {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br/><br/><br/>
<table class="tableWithFloatingHeader" style="border: 3px" align="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>t2 col header</th>
      <th>t2 col header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data1</td>
      <td>t2 data1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data2</td>
      <td>t2 data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data3</td>
      <td>t2 data3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data4</td>
      <td>t2 data4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data5</td>
      <td>t2 data5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data6</td>
      <td>t2 data6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data7</td>
      <td>t2 data7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data8</td>
      <td>t2 data8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data9</td>
      <td>t2 data9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data10</td>
      <td>t2 data10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data5</td>
      <td>t2 data5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data6</td>
      <td>t2 data6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data7</td>
      <td>t2 data7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data8</td>
      <td>t2 data8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data9</td>
      <td>t2 data9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data10</td>
      <td>t2 data10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data5</td>
      <td>t2 data5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data6</td>
      <td>t2 data6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data7</td>
      <td>t2 data7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data8</td>
      <td>t2 data8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data9</td>
      <td>t2 data9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data10</td>
      <td>t2 data10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data5</td>
      <td>t2 data5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data6</td>
      <td>t2 data6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data7</td>
      <td>t2 data7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data8</td>
      <td>t2 data8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data9</td>
      <td>t2 data9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data10</td>
      <td>t2 data10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data5</td>
      <td>t2 data5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data6</td>
      <td>t2 data6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data7</td>
      <td>t2 data7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data8</td>
      <td>t2 data8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data9</td>
      <td>t2 data9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data10</td>
      <td>t2 data10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data5</td>
      <td>t2 data5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data6</td>
      <td>t2 data6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data7</td>
      <td>t2 data7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data8</td>
      <td>t2 data8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data9</td>
      <td>t2 data9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data10</td>
      <td>t2 data10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data5</td>
      <td>t2 data5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data6</td>
      <td>t2 data6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data7</td>
      <td>t2 data7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data8</td>
      <td>t2 data8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data9</td>
      <td>t2 data9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data10</td>
      <td>t2 data10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data5</td>
      <td>t2 data5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data6</td>
      <td>t2 data6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data7</td>
      <td>t2 data7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data8</td>
      <td>t2 data8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data9</td>
      <td>t2 data9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data10</td>
      <td>t2 data10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data5</td>
      <td>t2 data5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data6</td>
      <td>t2 data6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data7</td>
      <td>t2 data7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data8</td>
      <td>t2 data8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data9</td>
      <td>t2 data9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>t2 data10</td>
      <td>t2 data10</td>
    </tr>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>t2 col footer</th>
        <th>t2 col footer</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Specify your problem, have you already tried anything?

Comment: I added the footer, but I am not sure what exactly to change in the javascript code. I am not that good in javascript. I replaced all 'top's with 'bottom' but it dint work out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the plugin
http://fixedheadertable.com/

Comment: Thats a great idea! But how would I sort the column data using that plugin?

Comment: sounds like a separate question to me.

Comment: Yes, it is a separate question indeed, I figured out that part. This plugin is not supported in IE9 though.

Comment: i wrote another plugin that does this, and it seems to work better then the one you linked. http://programmingdrunk.com/floatThead/